# Block element auto height of ul

Tags: html, css

I Have 3 UL's which have different heights and i would like them to have a border on the right hand side which reached the bottom of the containing div so they are all equal. I cannot add height to ul as the container si will be changing height from dynamic content being loaded

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zangief007/0ddev8rp/1/

It be great if the red line went all the way to the bottom of the div

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<ul>
                            <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">5</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">5</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">5</a></li>
                        </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    float:left;
    border-right:red solid 3px;
}
li{
    list-style:none;
    padding:10px;
}
div{
    background:grey;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Would it word to put each ul in its own div and add a right border to the div?

Comment: It won't work, because every div will have a height that is adjusted automatically. Having height of 100% for children won't work because the parent has no specified height.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to display the `div` as a table and the `ul` s as table-cells:

```
ul{
    border-right:red solid 3px;
    display:table-cell;
}
li{
    list-style:none;
    padding:10px;
}
div{
    background:grey;
    display: table;
}
```

Also see [your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ddev8rp/3/)

---

It has a limitation: it won't work for IE7.
See http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html for details.